# What is AmE's analog for 'one-off'?

Tags: word-request, american-english

What is AmE's analog for 'one-off'? Lexico says it's British.

Comment: As a Canadian, I use *one-off*, and I have also heard Americans use it. If it was once British, it isn't anymore.

Comment: Googloe Ngrams doesn't seem to handle hyphenated **one-off** when I try to produce a chart comparing US/UK corpora for the sequence **was a one-off**, but I can confirm that this usage (which only really gained traction in recent decades) is about 5 times more common in BrE than AmE. Which I must admit wouldn't have expected.

Comment: I see that **was a one-shot [wonder]** is twice as common in AmE as in BrE, but that's far less common than **one-off** both sides of the pond, and it's not really "equivalent" anyway. Americans probably just have to use more literal terms, such as **unique, isolated, unrepeatable,...**

Comment: What sense of the word? What context? The answer will depend on both of these so you need to include that information.

Comment: @Laurel I mean the adjective. It has only one adjectival meaning (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/one-off)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Why, it seems to fit, according to Lexico. Thanks

Comment: I think that would be a mistake. The first (and thus by implication, *primary*) definition of ***one-shot*** is *effective after only one attempt*, which doesn't really suit the normal context of ***one-off*** (a one-off victory over a superior opponent, for example). You shouldn't assume that just because Americans don't use idiomatic ***one-off*** so often as Brits, they must perforce have some "close analogue" that they ***do*** use *in exactly the same way*. That's just not how AmE/BrE differences work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment under the question, *a one-off* is about 5 times more common in the UK than in the US—at least according to Google Ngram Viewer when it comes to the printed word. (Although, annoyingly, the hyphenation doesn't seem to make a comparative graph possible.)

But the fact that *a one-off* is more common in UK English than in US English shouldn't be a deterrence to using it for a US audience. Even if it's not as common, I'd say that it's still quite understandable.

---

According to [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20one%20-%20off%2Ca%20onetime%20event%2Ca%20onetime%20thing%2Ca%20one%20-%20shot&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20one%20--%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20onetime%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20onetime%20thing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20one%20--%20shot%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20one%20--%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20onetime%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20onetime%20thing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20one%20--%20shot%3B%2Cc0), here are four phrases ranked in order of their commonality in print in US English:

1. *a one-off*
2. *a onetime event*
3. *a one-shot*
4. *a onetime thing*

[image: US English a one-off versus a onetime event versus a one-shot versus a onetime thing]

So, of those 4 phrases, *a one-off* is still the most common in US English. There is no reason to choose one of the others in its place.

---

However, taking *a one-off* and comparing it the more formal expressions suggested in comments under the question, as well as a couple of others, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+one+-+off%2Ca+unique+event%2Can+isolated+event%2Can+unrepeatable+event%2Ca+random+event%2C+a+chance+event&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20one%20--%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20unique%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20isolated%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20unrepeatable%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20random%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20chance%20event%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20one%20--%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20unique%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20isolated%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20unrepeatable%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20random%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20chance%20event%3B%2Cc0) shows the following for US English:

1. *an isolated event*
2. *a unique event*
3. *a random event*
4. *a chance event*
5. *a one-off*
6. *an unrepeatable event*

[image: US English a one-off versus an isolated, unique, random, chance, or unrepeatable event)]

---

For the sake of completeness, here is what [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20one%20-%20off%2Ca%20unique%20event%2Can%20isolated%20event%2Can%20unrepeatable%20event%2Ca%20random%20event%2Ca%20chance%20event&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20one%20--%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20unique%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20isolated%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20unrepeatable%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20random%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20chance%20event%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20one%20--%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20unique%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20isolated%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20unrepeatable%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20random%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20chance%20event%3B%2Cc0) shows for the same 6 phrases in UK English:

1. *a one-off*
2. *a unique event*
3. *an isolated event*
4. *a random event*
5. *a chance event*
6. *an unrepeatable event*

[image: UK English a one-off versus an isolated, unique, random, chance, or unrepeatable event]

---

Also keep in mind that Google Ngram Viewer only shows the occurrences of words and phrases in print. The occurrences of spoken words and phrases could be quite different—in particular, informal and colloquial expressions such as *a one-off*.

In short, I would not worry about *a one-off* being a problem in informal speech or writing in the US, despite the fact that it's less common in the US than in the UK.

If formal language is required, then *a one-off* probably shouldn't be used anyway, in either country. Based on these results, the top formal results are *an isolated event* in the US and *a unique event* in the UK, although there isn't much to distinguish them in terms of commonality, so either could be chosen without any difficulty.